# Carriage Return in an Array is causing Unexpected token error

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I'm attempting to retrieve a string of text that becomes corrupted when a Carriage Return is present.

There is a multi-line input field that allows the user it hit enter and type on the next line. There is a button that allows the user to save the note.

The save is happening as so...

```
if (save) note = $('#annotation_textarea').val();
```

Navigating to another page in the SPA app causes an Unexpected token error.

I tried to convert the carriage returns to 
 a la RegEx.

```
note.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/g,"<br />");
```

that didn't work.

Here's the code to reproduce the issue:

#### app.js

```
var mySceApp = angular.module('mySceApp', ['ngSanitize']);

mySceApp.controller("myAppController", function myAppController($http, $templateCache, $sce) {
  var self = this;
  $http.get("test_data.json", {cache: $templateCache}).success(function(userComments) {
    self.userComments = userComments;
  });
  self.explicitlyTrustedHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml(
      '<span onmouseover="this.textContent=&quot;Explicitly trusted HTML bypasses ' +
      'sanitization.&quot;">Hover over this text.</span>');
});
```

#### html

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="mySceApp">
  <head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
  <body>

<div ng-controller="myAppController as myCtrl">
  <i ng-bind-html="myCtrl.explicitlyTrustedHtml" id="explicitlyTrustedHtml"></i><br><br>
  <b>User comments</b><br>
  By default, HTML that isn't explicitly trusted (e.g. Alice's comment) is sanitized when
  $sanitize is available.  If $sanitize isn't available, this results in an error instead of an
  exploit.
  <div class="well">
    <div ng-repeat="userComment in myCtrl.userComments">
      <b>{{userComment.name}}</b>:
      <span ng-bind-html="userComment.htmlComment" class="htmlComment"></span>
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


  </body>
</html>
```

#### Test Data

```
[
  { "name": "Carriage Return test",
    "htmlComment":
        "<span onmouseover='this.textContent=\"PWN3D!\"'>Is <i>anyone</i> reading this?</span>"
  },
  { "name": "Bob",
    "htmlComment": "<i>Yes!</i>  Am I the only other one?"
  },
  { "name": "Hal",
    "htmlComment": "You,
     are
     not
     alone!"
  }
]
```

**Here's a plnkr**
http://plnkr.co/edit/RYReiYQfD0Vw8u0BeDVc?p=preview

Comment: Mock out the backend datasource and create a minimal example that reproduces the issue.  Without that we can't be sure that's actually the problem or that there isn't a better way to help you.

Comment: Thanks. Also, a plunkr should be supplemental. The complete (minimal) code we need to reproduce the problem should be in your question. The reason is, if plunkr goes down, your question becomes useless to future vistors. I've gone ahead and edited the code into the question.

Comment: Thanks George! I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not entirely sure what is going. I think the the safest will be to use `$sce` service and parse as html like

```
$sce.parseAsHtml(someValue)
```

Here is the documenation about this service:

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$sce

Comment: I've been going that route to no avail. I updated the question above with a plnkr.